# Using logcat after pairing android tablet with bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, debugging, logging

For some reason, it seems that my log messages don't come in after I connect my tablet with other devices through bluetooth. I create a a log message saying Log.d (TAG, "On Create") and I see this in my logcat, but then when I connect the tablet with a device, this suddenly disappears from my logcat and the messages that are placed afterwards don't appear at all (verified by using toasts instead). Is this a problem with bluetooth or is there something elseI'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try on it

```
 Log.e(TAG, "On Create")
```